# When is a task considered few-shot learning?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

When reading about few-shot learning, I can never seem to find an exact definition. When the concept is explained, it is often done by saying something along the lines of 'using few data samples'.

Is there a precise definition of few-shot learning, or when a task is considered few-shot learning? When the term 'N-way-K-shot learning' is used, are there any boundaries on which values N and K can have?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about AI theory and/or methodology - please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artificial-intelligence/info

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind few-shot learning is to train a classifier using only a small number of labelled samples. More precisely, given N classes and k samples, the aim is to use  samples per class where m << k to train the classifier. Few-shot learning is a popular option when the number of available labelled samples is limited.

However, when it comes to implementing few-shot learning, one popular method is to use contrastive learning to fine-tune an existing model to learn the similarities between samples belonging to the same class.

SetFit is a few-shot learning framework that uses contrastive learning for fine-tuning sentence transformers to be used for text classification. I suggest you read SetFit's paper (available on Axriv; here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.11055). I believe it has the technical details you need to answer your question. Moreover, SetFit's implementation is available on GitHub (here: https://github.com/huggingface/setfit).

I hope it helped.